# Determining the target for unittest.mock.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a some tests for a library I've been developing. It has the following structure.

```
lib
|---__init__.py
|---mod1.py
|---mod2.py
|---mod3.py
tests
|---__init__.py
|---test_mod1.py
```

In **init**.py of tests folder, I added the path of the library to the `sys.path` variable and them made all the imports. i.e. `from lib import mod1, mod2, mod3`. In *test_mod1.py* I did `from . import mod1`

The problem now is that I want to patch a function in *mod1.py*. I tried `mock.patch('mod1.func1')` but that didn't work then I tried `mock.patch('.mod1.func1')` that too is not working.
How do I determine the target for the patch?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify where the function that you want to mock is located.

In this case, if `func1` is the following in `lib.mod1`:

```
def func1(a, b):
    return a + b
```

then the following should work:

```
@mock.patch('lib.mod1.func1', mock.Mock(return_value=3))
def test_mod1():
    result = mod1.func1(100, 200)
    assert result == 3  # not 300 because we mocked it
```

You could also implement it as follows:

```
@mock.patch('lib.mod1.func1')
def test_mod1(mocked_func1):
    mocked_func1.return_value = 3
    result = mod1.func1(100, 200)
    assert result == 3  # not 300 because we mocked it
```